# getElementsByTagName - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, getelementsbytagname

I am working on learning how to parse through javascript nodes to gather information in various ways.

When I run the code included below, all works until I get to line that says:

`for(var i = 0; i < olElements.childNodes.length; i++){`

I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Here is my full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.1">
function getNodeValue(){
    var olElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");
    var a = olElement.getElementsByTagName("li");
    console.log("The ordered list contains " + a.length + " items.\n\n");

    console.log(a[a.length - 1].lastChild.nodeValue + "\n\n");



    for(var i = 0; i < olElement.childNodes.length; i++){
        if(olElement.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1 ){
            var childOf = olElement.childNodes[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < childOf.childNodes.length; j++){
                if(childOf.childNodes[j].nodeType == 3 ){
                    console.log(childOf.childNodes[j].nodeValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var oltags = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
    for(var k = 0; k < oltags.childNodes.length; k++){
        if(oltags.childNodes[k].nodeType == 1 ){
            var childOf = oltags.childNodes[k];
            for(var l = 0; l < childOf.childNodes.length; l++){
                if(childOf.childNodes[l].nodeType == 3 ){
                    console.log(childOf.childNodes[l].nodeValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
window.onload = getNodeValue;
</script>
```

The HTML is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Getting Node Values</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Things To Do</h1>
    <ol id="toDoList">
        <li>Mow the lawn</li>
        <li>Clean the windows</li>
        <li>Answer emails</li>
        <li>Learn javascript</li>
        <li>Learn more javascript</li>
        <li>And learn even more!</li>
    </ol>

    <p id="toDoNotes">Make sure all are completed by 8pm so I can watch the game on TV!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is my usage of getElementsByTagName in the code

`var oltags = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");`

incorrect? And, if so, why? Or is something else causing this problem?

Follow up question: Are there a better ways to access text nodes inside of elements than the ways I have done it here?

Comment: var oltags = document.getElementsByTagName("ol") will return HTML collection and you can access each element by its index

Comment: That is what I used above. I do not understanding why it is giving the "undefined" error when I use `oltags.childNodes.length`. I will read the article referenced by @jsquerylover below.

Comment: Also, can anyone tell me why the down votes on this for me? Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Cause oltags does not have property childNodes, but oltags[0] does have

Comment: Thanks @OlenaHoral ! So are you saying that when I use `var olElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");` to access the ol with the id toDoList, my variable has a property childNodes, but if I try to use `var oltags = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");` to access all of the ol tags I do not have a childNodes property with that variable without using the index. I am beginning to understand. Thanks!!!

Comment: The reason behind this is that there can be only  one  item with certain id on a page and calling getElementById you'll get a reference to this only item. On the opposite there can be many items with certain tag on a page that's why you get a collection of such items  while calling getElementsByTagName. Note the ending - in first case its getElement in the second - getElements

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the tag names?

```
var a = olElement.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if(a[i].nodeType == 1 ){

//etc
```

Comment: That was the first way in my code that I used to access the text nodes. I was trying other ways after that. I am trying to understand why that worked but the later code did not. Why was I getting the 'undefined' error?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.getElementById("idOfElement")` and then iterate on it's child nodes

Comment: Thanks. I did that earlier in my code. I was just trying to see if other ways would work as well. Not understanding why I got the 'undefined' error on the line of code that I referenced. Ultimately I am just trying to see all of the ways to access different nodes and nodetypes and grab their info.